# RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am setting up a `RecyclerView` inside a `Fragment` following the Android docs example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

I pasted my code below, there is not much. (The only difference is I'm using a Fragment instead of an Activity).

The error I'm getting is:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

All solutions to this problem online are to add `false` argument in layout inflation for fragment. But I've already done this, and I still get the error.

My code:

**MainActivity**

```
...
mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new NewsFragment()).commit();
...
```

**NewsFragment**

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_layout,container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new NewsAdapter(new String[]{"hello","world","qwert","test","greg","peck"});
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return v;

    }
}
```

**NewsAdapter**

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(TextView tv) {
            super(tv);
            mTextView = tv;
        }
    }

    public NewsAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public NewsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent, false);

        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(tv);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: on which line is the exception thrown??

Comment: No direct reference to a specific line in my code... the error is exactly like this: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Ff-s9dd60F8/VhOixvKRzyI/AAAAAAAAWzE/2-BvcBBn9RM/s1600/Snip20151006_1.png

Comment: well you need to debug with breakpoints, see which view's attach operation is throwing the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(tv);
```

Change it to:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
```

The text view is already having a parent. That's why you are getting this error.

Updated code:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(tv);
           mTextView= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        }
    }

    public NewsAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public NewsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent, false);


        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: But my `ViewHolder` constructor requires a `TextView` argument. Should I change this back to `View` argument and cast to `TextView` inside constructor?

Comment: Yes .After that it wil work. The reason is textview already having parent.